# Comparing X-Y Co-ordinates

Tags: spatial

I have 500 x-y co-ordinates with five different variables so around 100 for each variable.  I would like to compare how packed the clusters are, also how far they are away from their desired points and are the co-ordinates groupings dispersions and positions (x,Y) statistically significant or just random.  What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Just to make sure -- these 5 sets of (x,y) pairs?  Or are there 5 y's for each x? (Or something else?)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is the cluster analysis.
So, you might want to take a look at this [resource](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html) for learning more on handling and analyzing clusters in R.

And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is a generalized resource, which would help you in understanding clusters and the metrics and techniques associated to dealing with them.
([on the Stata blog](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/cluster-analysis/%23k))